# how to code Multi threading a for loop curve fitting

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, curve-fitting

I have a "for loop" that runs over 100 range values and for each value, I call scipy.optimize to do a non-linear curve fitting. When I run it on a 4-core desktop, I see the CPU utilization as 100% which is just 1 core fully used. I want to use multi threading if that will help or if not, multi processing. I just started doing python for the last 3 days and so is there a simple example that I can use to modify my current for loop.

Comment: Additionally, I will have the output of each pass in the for loop returning a value and that needs to be collected in one place to be written to a single file. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

My Python BSD-licensed curve and surface fitting library has several parallel programming examples, look in the example code for

"Parallel region begins"

and

" Parallel region ends"

Let me know if you have any questions.  My email address is zunzun@zunzun.com and the code is in the Google Code Repository at:

http://code.google.com/p/pyeq2/

Be aware that you are about to jump into the deep end of the pool, so to speak.  I advise looking into the Python multiprocessing module's documentation.

James